# Morphological Filtering : how to disable in d3d11

Tags: direct3d, ati

I want to disable Morphological Filtering in my application.

My computer use  AMD Radeon r7 m260 display card.

My application that developed with c++ use skia and ANGLE. The ANGLE use d3d11.

When I enable Morphological Filtering, my application looks blurry.

I can disable Morphological Filtering with AMD setting ui, but I want to disable Morphological Filtering in my c++ code.

Do you have good methods.

Thank you!

Comment: The same problem occurred with angle-d3d11, after NVIDIA turned on FXAA.There is no problem with angle-d3d9.

Comment: Note that "Morphological Filtering" is an AMD only feature so it's not part of the standard Direct3D API surface. This is entirely an AMD-controlled behavior in their driver.

Comment: Hello, I want to ask, there is no way to set made in d3d11 amd open and don't open "Morphological Filtering" display the same?If not, why is d3d9 on and off display the same?

Comment: Again, this is not a Direct3D feature. It's an AMD "value added feature". From some internet searches, the feature seems to work better for Direct3D9 but it's not something exposed in any Direct3D API. It's something AMD's software is doing.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of see what you mean.Then I can only turn off "morph filter" in amd graphics card and "FXAA" in NVIDIA graphics card.Is that what you mean?